# How to auth by facebook better?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, facebook, spring-security

I have a simple app with implemented facebook oauth by [scribe java](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava) as in [example](https://github.com/plechi/spring-security-scribe). It works fine with JSP. But now I want to implement angularJS frontend. I found an [example](http://ngmodules.org/modules/authenticate.js) with auth by ajax:

```
 login: function () {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                $http({
                    url: config.host + config.loginUrl,
                    method: 'POST',
                    async: false
                }).success(function (data) {
                    user = data;
                    lastUser = data;
                    defer.resolve(user);
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('AuthenticateJS.login', user);
                }).error(function () {
                    defer.reject();
                });
```

And when I call this function by click on Login href it throws an error:

> (index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=99999999999999&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin%3Fnull.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I understand that this problem appears because I inserted http://localhost:8080 as origin for application in Facebook app but how to solve this I don't know.

If this way is impossible (as I read on stackoveflow), which one will be better? Maybe it exists a way when I can simple take my springsecurity principal and set it in angular and store it as cookie on localstorage?

Comment: Maybe you can use offcial facebook JS SDK. They also provide a basic wrapper for Angular: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/angularjs

Comment: But in this case I'll authenticate on frontend, what is not so secure and I'll need to send usertoken on each query to backend

Comment: Even if facebook say:  *use the Facebook SDK for JavaScript , which is the recommended method to add Facebook Login to your website*... I recommand you to create a vhost over your localhost to be able to put "mydomain.local.com" instead of localhost and add *mydomain.local.com* into allowed urls in your app

Comment: You can not load the login dialog via AJAX – you have to redirect the user to it. (The reason should be pretty obvious – users need to be able to verify via their browser address bar, that they are indeed sending their login credentials to Facebook, and not some phishing site.)